# Functions which map Lebesgue measurable sets into Lebesgue measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, morphism, measurable-sets

Can you give an alternative description of the set of functions which map Lebesgue measurable sets into Lebesgue measurable sets?

I think that it is enough to consider Lebesgue measurable sets on the real line, the generalizations for other spaces may be interesting too, however.

Comment: Perhaps not interesting, but one characterization is that null sets are mapped to null sets.

Comment: @DavidMitra: This is a necessary condition. But without assuming anything else about $f $ (like being continuous or mapping Borel sets to Borel sets), I don't see the sufficiency.

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes, you're right. I overlooked that more about $f$ wasn't assumed in the OP.